# login page using zend framework custom layout

Tags: zend-framework

i will try to integrate css template in my zend project.i had integrate it with layout resources.it is working file..but now i want different layout when user render log in page and different layout after log in. i am confuse how to achieve different layout for different view.

this my bootstarp.php file which add layout to pages when render..how can i render diffrent layout for login page

```
<?php

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{   

    function _initViewHelpers()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('layout');

        $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
        $view = $layout->getView();
        $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
        $view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type', 'text/html;charset=utf-8');
        $view->headTitle()->setSeparator(' - ');
        $view->headTitle('Zend Framework Tutorial');
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably dont want to do it in the boo
[Layout quickstart](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.layout.quickstart.html#zend.layout.quickstart.mvc)